# What is meant by the term " BruteForce " in programming?

Tags: terminology

I have tried Googling the term "Brute force". But I come across two different definitions which leave me confused.

Definition 1: Brute Force is the most basic and simplest type of algorithm. A Brute Force Algorithm is the straightforward approach to a problem i.e., the first approach that comes to our mind on seeing the problem.

Definition 2: Brute-force search or exhaustive search, also known as generate and test, is a very general problem-solving technique that consists of systematically enumerating all possible candidates for the solution and checking whether each candidate satisfies the problem’s statement.

Can someone answer in Yes or NO that  **if a particular algorithm does not search the entire solution space but happens to be logically  straightforward or the first approach that comes to mind , then would it be " Brute Force "** ?

Comment: both are correct, most basic approach that comes to our mind - check all possible candidates and test them

Comment: I would say your interpretation / example of definition 1 is not what was intended. Definition 2 is probably more accurate, but I don't think the two definitions are supposed to be contradictory.

Comment: @MattTimmermans  No, that does not answer my question. I have edited my question to be more specific. Can you give an answer to the question that is in bold ?

Comment: No, an algorithm isn't brute force just because it's simple.  It needs to apply a "lot" of cycles, with minimal finesse.  That doesn't necessarily mean exhaustively searching a solution space, though.  Long multiplication is brute force, while Karatsuba multiplication is not, for example.

Comment: The first one isn't a definition, it's just a description. You can't define a kind of algorithm by "what comes to mind first" or "simplest" because different programmers have different minds, and simplicity is subjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, someone can answer: I can.

My answer is: NO.  When we say 'brute force' we talk about a solution space that can be exhaustively searched.  Definition 1 omits that limitation, so it is false.

If you see Definition 1 in the context of all exhaustively searcheable solution spaces, it stays false, since 'our mind' is different for everyone.

Comment: I think if one was searching for a counterexample to Fermat's Last Theorem by just trying every triple of numbers in some order, we would consider that brute force even though the solution space is not finite.

Comment: Hm.  You're right.  So 'exhaustively' is too limiting.